# SonarScanner on Virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, sonarqube, virtualenv, sonarqube-scan

sonar-scanner for python choose only global python environment. My global python is set to python 3.5 and I have a pip virtualenv on python 2.7 with required libraries.

Even if I execute sonar-scanner code in the virtual environment, It choose the global python 3.5. I found it because there were issues to use print statement with `()`

Is there anyway I can use my virtual env path as a option to sonar scanner

Comment: the main clue is that venv is on python2 which uses print statements without brackets. And it's the bug shows in the sonar scanner, which makes it a python3 run

Comment: - activate pip virtual environment  

```source /path/to/venv/bin/activate```  

- run sonnar scanner on the project directory  

```sonar-scanner   -Dsonar.projectKey=project_key   -Dsonar.sources=.   -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000   -Dsonar.login=c6a578423793a28d12884e8ecf565b8```  

- The question is not about this. I know it's not using the virtual environment. The question is **how to use the virtual environment**. As you can see